# How to change the basic mysql query (related tables) to Laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, frameworks

I have related tables.
So, how to convert basic query to Laravel that return same value with my query?

```
$result=$koneksi->query("SELECT * FROM user, city where user.id_city=city.id_city and id_user='1'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
$id_user=$row['id_user'];
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code. You're using both styles here inconsistently. Should be `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)`.

Answer (score 0):

use DB;

```
DB::table('user')->Join('city', 'user.id_city', '=', 'city.id_city')->where('id_user','=',1);
```

regarding your core php mysql query this query would work in your laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you have models for each table, if not set that up. The default id column is usually 'id' so it is good if you also can change that to make Laravels magic work right out of the box.

Then add relationship in your model classes.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
}

class City extends Model
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to do

```
User::with('city')->find(1)
```